# Custom back button has extra unwanted space

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationitem

I'm developing a Xamarin.iOS application with two supported languages i.e. English and Arabic. I want to use a custom back button. The button is placed in the navigation bar, however, it has some extra space which I want to get rid of.

Below is the code that I have used to add the button

```
var leftBarButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("IcArrowLeft.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (s, e) =>
{
    DismissViewController(true, null);
});
```

Refer to the below screenshots of the result. I want to get rid of the space marked in red

[image: English] 
[image: Arabic]

Below is the image that I'm using as the back icon

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `navigationBar` as you want .

```
public class xxxViewController: UIViewController
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);



            NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;


            double height = IsiphoneX();

            UIView backView = new UIView()
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
                Frame = new CGRect(0,20,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, height),

            };


            UIButton backBtn = new UIButton() {

                Frame = new CGRect(20, height-44, 40, 44),
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18),

            } ;



            backBtn.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("IcArrowLeft.png"),UIControlState.Normal);
            backBtn.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -10, 0, 0);
            backBtn.TouchUpInside += BackButton_TouchUpInside;

            UILabel titleLabel = new UILabel() {
                Frame=new CGRect(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width/2-75, 0,150, height),
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20),
                Text = "xxx",
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                Lines = 0,

            };

            UILabel line = new UILabel() {

                Frame = new CGRect(0, height, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 0.5),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black,

            };

            backView.AddSubview(backBtn);
            backView.AddSubview(titleLabel);
            backView.AddSubview(line);

            View.AddSubview(backView);
        }


         double IsiphoneX()
        {

            double height = 44;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom > 0.0)
                {
                    height = 64;
                }
            }

            return height;
        }

        private void BackButton_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DismissViewController(true, null);
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
        }

    }
```

ou can set the property of title , backButton and navigationBar as you need (such as text , color ,BackgroundColor ,font e.g.)